# Visual Studio. Неправильно выводит ошибки

Tags: c#, visual-studio

После того как во время отладки кода произошел `BSOD`(синий экран) - у меня магическим образом стали подсвечиваться ошибки. Вернее не так, они до компиляции вообще перестали находиться.. Если копировать метод в другой класс - он не подсветит ошибку, что, скажем, не хватает какой то либы, то тех пор, пока ты не нажмешь `F5` и он не начнет его компилить. После устранения ошибки проблема такая же`(см. скриншот)`. Проблема устранена - но он ее будет выводить до тех пор, пока не соберешь проект заново.

Мб какая то функция отключилась и ее нужно снова включить? Местами это очень неудобно...

[image]

Comment: почистите папки obj/.vs и перезапустите студию(папки чистить желательно когда проект не открыт)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у тебя повреждены какие то файлы для работы visual studio.Я бы на твоем месте переустановил программу ибо искать в чем проблема очень сложно. Прости за такой очевидный ответ. Можешь еще почистить кэш но это вряд ли тебе поможет.(хотя попытаться стоит) и да если  будешь чистить закрой visual studio.

Comment: и еще есть вопрос: какая студия у тебя стоит?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос